# intent crash android java

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hello ive been coding with android java trying to make a button which when pressed would let the user select a image from their gallery to then be displayed on the ImageView. The problem is it crashes each time the button is pressed. all of the needed manifest permissions i have read, write and manage external data. ive tried startActivityForResult but it was deprecated since android 11.The code is ran from a class which is called from the main activity (class is not static) how can i get the user to select a image then after display it in a image view.
code:

````
 ActivityResultLauncher<String> launcher = registerForActivityResult
            (new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri> () {
                @Override public void onActivityResult (Uri uri) {
        images.setImageURI(uri);
                } });
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                launcher.launch("image/*");
            }
        });
```
error:
```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.an.rindr, PID: 13121
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5584)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api16Impl.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:809)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:246)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:243)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:175)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
                                                                                                        at com.an.rindr.home$2.onClick(home.java:152)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7881)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16201)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7858)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30863)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
````

Answer (score 0):

Hello ive found the answer the main problem was i needed some implications

```
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```

and i needed to check if activity was null or not eg:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                if (activity != null) {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
```